# What's the easiest way to hook into multiple BTC exchanges?

Tags: currencies, buy-bitcoins, python, arbitrage

If you want to compare prices of BTC across multiple exchanges, is there a central mechanism or place to do so? I have been unable to find such a thing from my research

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are such services.

[bitcoincharts.com offers such an overview](https://bitcoincharts.com/markets/), though you may get confused from the many fiat currencies.

[CoinDesk's chart](http://www.coindesk.com/price/) is much cleaner, only uses USD, and you can easily choose which exchanges to regard. However, CoinDesk lists far fewer exchanges than bitcoincharts.com.

There are several services – for example [BitcoinAverage](https://bitcoinaverage.com/en/bitcoin-price/btc-to-usd) – which attempt to plot the average price.

If you want to, you can use the APIs of the exchanges you're interested in, and write a script or small program which shows the current prices.

Comment: Thanks UTF-8. The main concernI have is would I need separate accounts to access and trade on each exchange?

Comment: Would I (for example) have an account on bitcoincharts.com, log in with my API and be able to trade on each offered exchange?

Comment: log in via the API with my account**

Comment: I of course don't know this for every exchange but I think there probably are very few (if any) which let you trade without being logged into an account at that exchange. BitcoinCharts' API isn't for trading, it's only for querying the trading data they collected using the APIs of exchanges. BitcoinCharts isn't an exchange or some kind of meta exchange. PS: You can edit your comments within the first 5 minutes so you don't have to post 3 comments.

Comment: Yes that frustrated me, thanks for the tip. So does my description in the second comment describe any services you know? One account that to an exchange or service that interfaces with other exchanges?

Comment: No, I don't know one. But I just googled it and there seems to have been one: https://metaexchange.info However, they're closing down. You should probably google this yourself and ask a separate question if you can't find anything because these comments are drifting away from the original topic and may be deleted.